# NextJS _app.tsx issue -error - ./pages/_app.tsx:3:12

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

Currently i'm having an issue while creating some custom script on my NextJs Project.
here's error Log;

```
error - ./pages/_app.tsx:3:12
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "from"

  1 | import React from 'react'
  2 | import '../styles/globals.css'
> 3 | import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
    |             ^
  4 |
  5 | export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  6 |   return <Component {...pageProps} />
```

actually i didn't change anything on _app.tsx

hope there's an expert could reviewing this. and do the magic.

Regards
Mad.

i already try to delete node_module and reinstalling it again, and also add the necessary depedencies.

however the result still the same

Comment: It looks like you are receiving a TypeScript error. It seems that TypeScript is incorrectly interpreting the use of the type keyword. Perhaps you are compiling the code as if it were JavaScript. Try removing the type instruction to see if the error is different (it will probably be about AppProps).

Comment: Yes David, it's wrongly interpreted. currently i ignore the typescript and regenerate it on Js. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the babel setting is missing. Try adding presets

add .babelrc file

```
 "presets": ["next/babel"],
```